# Converting to factors

Tags: r

I have a data set as below:

```
 age    sex  Cond  label
range1   M    1      0
range2   M    2      1
range3   F    4      1
```

with more rows..all data columns are discrete.
I intend to use the `hc`, `gs`, `bn`, `tan` of `bnlearn` package in R.What data transformation should I use? How should I convert the data to factors?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question, it is very straightforward to convert to `factor`.  Just loop through the columns of interest with `lapply` and apply the `factor`.  Then update the original dataset with the output.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, factor)
```

In case, we are only looking for subset of columns, say, 'age', 'sex', subset the dataset and then loop through those

```
df1[c('age', 'sex')] <- lapply(df1[c('age', 'sex')], factor)
```